# Bluetooth stopped working after firmware update

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I was happily listening to music through a bluetooth speaker, snap asked to upgrade my firmware, and after restarting the bluetooth doesn't work.

By "does not work", I mean that on the Bluetooth tab of the Ubuntu 20.04 settings menu, it says "Bluetooth Turned Off" and pressing the On button does nothing.

On this machine, I have always had a problem with bluetooth not working after a soft reboot. I have tried a hard reboot, restarting the bluetooth service, reinstalling the bluetooth modules, and booting under a previous kernel (I'm on 5.15.0-53 and tried 5.14.0-1054). I have checked the following,

- `sudo rfkill list all`, which says nothing is blocked
- `sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service`, which says the service is active
- `dmesg | grep bluetooth -i` elicits the following

```
[    2.383331] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is unblocked
[    2.417508] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.417562] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    2.417564] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.417571] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.417575] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.417581] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.763262] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.763266] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.763272] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   14.381028] Bluetooth: hci0: Execution of wmt command timed out
[   14.381036] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send wmt patch dwnld (-110)
[   14.381054] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to set up firmware (-110)
```

The posts about those errors involve either an inability to boot or imply that the problem went away on its own. Does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: This problem continued until the next kernel update a few days later, at which point the bluetooth spontaneously started working. If you're reading this in the future, I can only recommend patience and prayer.